# plotlyR subplot error in plots[[i]][["frames"]] : subscript out of bounds

Tags: r, plotly

I am using R 3.4.2 with package plotly version '4.7.1'

I first prepare this plot (which works):

```
x = structure(c(1444262400, 1444348800, 1444608000, 1444694400, 1444780800, 
            1444867200, 1444953600, 1445212800, 1445299200, 1445385600, 1445472000, 
            1445558400, 1445817600, 1445904000, 1445990400, 1446076800, 1446163200
), tzone = "GMT", tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), class = c("POSIXct", 
                                                             "POSIXt"))

y = c(-68.1377966700034, -68.5283603030953, -68.533877757571, -66.7349127872575, 
      -66.0681953259191, -67.6301142574414, -69.6710392385029, -70.170692866109, 
      -70.0701763503189, -71.9537057278669, -72.0177423408879, -68.300778528265, 
      -68.559662880874, -68.5621379677293, -69.2857358836203, -73.4822677099078, 
      -75.3170151811821)

p = plotly::plot_ly(x = x, y = y, type = "scatter", mode = "lines", line=list(dash = NULL), name = "margin", visible = NULL) %>% 
  plotly::layout(xaxis = NULL, yaxis = list(type = "linear", title=NULL), title="margin", legend = NULL, shapes = NULL)
```

However the subplot below doesn't work!

```
plotly::subplot(p, p, nrow=2, shareX = TRUE)
```

I get this error: `Error in plots[[i]][["frames"]] : subscript out of bounds`

Do you get the same error?

Comment: subplot(p, p, nrows = 2, shareX = TRUE) is working. you have a **s** missing in **nrow**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @MLavoie commented, it is just the missing `s` at the end of `nrow` argument. I had the same problem, the error message is confusing, the mistake is embarrassingly simple.

Comment: Had the same issue. The error message is completely misleading.

Answer (score 1):

Just a contribution (I put it as an answer as I don't have the right to comment).

I encountered this error by misspelling another option in subplot. Instead of `shareX` I wrote `sharedX`, finding the same error `Error in plots[[i]][["frames"]] : subscript out of bounds`

The correct spelling is :

```
subplot(f1,g,g2, nrows = 3, shareX = TRUE)
```

Comment: If you post comments as answers, you're likely to get those answers downvoted, which makes you lose points, and puts you further away from your goal of having enough rep to comment. We generally prefer to close questions that are just typos anyway

Comment: I thought of my answer as a (small) contribution. I also thought the up/down voting system reflected the usefulness of the answer (provided it is linked to the question), and not a convention. My intention was to add something useful. Apologies if not in line with the forum rules.